# Small spots on EOS m50 sensor

Tags: canon, sensor, mirrorless, aps-c

I had open my lens of Canon EOS m50 while I am on a ferry to a local island near by. Once I reach home I saw few spots on sensor which doesn't look like dust. I used swabs and cleaned the sensor it become clean but even if I took pictures on high aparture value like f20 and above I can see light spots still exist and which I am not able to remove using wet cleaning. Any idea what should I do now?
[image]
[image]

So here I have 2 images. First one taken on f30 of my white kitchen wall and same image I did a dehaze in light room. After dehaze the dots are visible.
Image taken on f32
[image]
Image taken on f14
[image]

Comment: I'd give cleaning another try after filtering the air in the work area. I also wouldn't use F-numbers higher than F8, unless there is a specific reason to do so (aside from demonstrating sensor dust). You can also try the "Dust Delete Data" function.